# How to scroll several times in order to find an element?

Tags: python, android, selenium, touch-event, appium-android

**I want to create a script to keep scrolling until the desired element is found using:**

```
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
```

The page is an Events page with different games titles.

All I got so far is the single scrolling:

```
# swipe down
time.sleep(1)
print('Scrolling the page..')
time.sleep(4)
touch = TouchAction(driver)
touch.long_press(x=500, y=1800).move_to(x=500, y=400).release().perform()
time.sleep(2)
print('PASS - Step 1. Page was scrolled')
```

Element is searched with:

```
selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

```
# Game name
time.sleep(1)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
Event_Name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@text="Event name"]//ancestor::*[contains(@class, "android.widget.LinearLayout")]')))
Event_Name.click()
time.sleep(2)
Game_title = driver.find_element_by_id('com.project.projectname:id/eventName')
print('PASS - Step 2. ' + Game_title.text + ' game card was clicked')
time.sleep(2)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
Game_size_GameName = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'com.project.projectname:id/size')))
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
for size in Game_size_Gamename:
    if '55.68 MB' == size.text:
        print('PASS - Step 3. User is on the ' + Game_title.text + ' product page')
    else:
        print('FAIL - Step 3. Failed to redirect user')
time.sleep(2)
Events_tab_title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'com.project.projectname:id/screenTitle')))
back_button.click()
print('PASS - Step 11. User is back on the ' + Events_tab_title.text + ' tab')
time.sleep(2)
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Mention: Not all the elements are visible and that's why I need to scroll the page through the script.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few methods for scrolling webpage to element. Some of them work but scrolled down page to a place just above element I needed. The best working was the JavaScript one:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('element_id')
context.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()
```

Comment: Element cannot be found so the script will not scroll and is throwing the error for element not found